# Windows 8.1 XAML Wrap Stackpanel Children

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have a bunch of listviews inside a Stackpanel with a horizontal orientation. I want the lists to wrap once the reach the end of the Stackpanel.

This seems easy to me but I cannot seem to figure out how.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`StackPanel` does not wrap. Look at `WrapGrid` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it using a `StackPanel` as the container. Usually I use a `Grid` as the parent container. It's more flexible.

Something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListView Grid.Column="0"/>
    <ListView Grid.Column="1"/>
    <ListView Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: thanks for your thoughts. so i'm uncertain how this would work and wrap given a width. can you give me an example? I've updated my post to show what I'm going for.

Comment: oh i just see now your "sketch". I thought you had a fixed number of `ListView` elements. My answer will only work if you know _a priori_ how much rows and columns of `ListView` elements you want

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with an ItemsControl and use WrapGrid as its ItemsPanel template. Here is the code i am using:

```
<ItemsControl Width="Auto" Height="Auto" IsHitTestVisible="False" ItemsSource="{Binding AnnotationTypesShown}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="50" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,5,0">
                        <Image Source="{Binding IconImage}" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="25" Height="25"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TypeName}" Width="Auto" Margin="5,10,5,0" Style="{StaticResource DefaultTextBlockStyle}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top"></WrapGrid>                        
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Here is the result on full view
[image]

and in wrapped view

[image]